# SharePoint 2010 on VMWare Player - Step by step instructions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, installation, virtual-machine

I am looking for detailed instructions on how to install SharePoint 2010 on VMWare Player.

Ideally I'd like to install additional applications on top of SharePoint, like SSRS or PerformancePoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you would prefer ready image and not wanting to specifically learn how to do the installation you can get ready bunch like this:

1. Download [2010 IW Demo VM](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417)
2. [Convert VHD](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/5_0) to VMWare Player compatible, or with other free converter tools as described [here](http://platinumdogs.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/migrating-virtual-machines-from-microsoft-hyper-v-vhd-to-vmware/)

I understand you asked for "detailed instructions", but I couldn't tell was it for the purpose to learn how to self install everything, or just to get to the goal of having everything set up and ready to proceed with additional application installations (SSRS, PerformancePoint).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. The goal is to get the applications, not to learn the process.